# How to unset proxy from pip?

Tags: python, terminal, pip, proxy, ubuntu-20.04

I have unset proxy `172.16.102.28:8080` in the settings option as well as in the bash terminal in my Ubuntu 20.04 system.
There is no proxy of any kind set in the system currently.
But whenever I am trying to install a python package via pip, the following error comes up.

```sh
name@dev:~$ pip install shutil
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after
connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
object at 0x7f3e43b94670>, 'Connection to 172.16.102.28 timed out. 
(connect timeout=15)')': /simple/shutil/
```

My pip executable is located at `~/.local/bin/` 
My `etc/apt/apt.conf` file is empty
My `/etc/environmemt` file only contains path
My `/etc/bash.bashrc` doesn't have any proxy set

Comment: Try using `python3 -m pip install shutil`.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen still showing the same error. Is there any way to remove proxy from the pip command or something? My pip is located at ~/.local/bin/pip

Comment: Try: `pip install --proxy=user:pass@server:port shutil`

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen showing same error

Comment: Are you able to download the package using curl? For example: `curl -sSL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/fa/c1f7bfb61674f69fb2694bda0ef475a6b8b915a5c36105648dd58a6f200a/pytest-shutil-1.7.0.tar.gz`

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen I entered the above command and the prompt is still not free. Don't know why its taking so much time. Edit - I finally got the error message curl: (28) Failed to connect to 172.16.102.28 port 8080: Connection timed out

Comment: I think you have your connection settings messed up. Unfortunately, I am not a network expert, and can't help you with that. Wish you all the best to get it resolved, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just had to restart my system and the problem was solved.